# React Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. To fix, cancel all subscriptions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

getting the above warning when trying to change a value inside a modal:

I have a popup and when I change the value of the country code field inside the modal everything is fine. But as soon as I save or close the modal, the value of the state variable becomes undefined.

Main Modal File:

```
const EditDetailsModal = props => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const intl = useIntl()
    const shouldShowModal = useSelector(selectors.shouldShowEditDetailsModal)
  const name = useSelector(selectors.getName)
  const email = useSelector(selectors.getEmail)
    const phoneNumber = useSelector(selectors.getPhone)
    const country = useSelector(selectors.getCountry)
  const phoneCode = useSelector(selectors.getPhoneCountryCode)
    const [newName, setNewName] = React.useState(name)
    const [newEmail, setNewEmail] = React.useState(email)
    const [newPhone, setNewPhone] = React.useState(phoneNumber)
  const [newPhoneCode, setNewPhoneCode] = React.useState(phoneCode)
    
    const _handleOnModalHide = React.useCallback(() => {
    setNewEmail(email)
    setNewName(name)
    setNewPhone(phoneNumber)
    setNewCountry(country)
    setRequestPhoneValue(phoneNumber)
        dispatch(actions.hideEditDetailsModal())
    }, [dispatch, name, setNewName, email, newEmail, setNewEmail, phoneNumber, setNewPhone, country, setNewCountry, setRequestPhoneValue ])

  const _phoneCountryCodeChangeCallback = React.useCallback((code) => {
    setNewPhoneCode(code)
  },[setNewPhoneCode])

    const _handleSaveBtnClick = React.useCallback(() => {
        if (isSaveBtnActive) {
            dispatch(actions.startRequestEditPersonalDetails())
            setError('')
            editPersonalDetails({
                name: newName,
                email: newEmail,
                phone: requestPhoneValue,
                country: requestCountryValue,
                oldEmail: email,
        phone_code: newPhoneCode,
            }).then(response => {
                if (response && response.data && response.data.data) {
                    dispatch(actions.successEditPersonalDetails())
                    dispatch(actions.savePersonalDetails(response.data.data))
                    _handleOnModalHide()
                } else {
                    dispatch(actions.errorEditPersonalDetails())
                    if (response.data.errors[0] && response.data.http_message) {
                        setError(response.data.errors[0])
                    } else {
                        setError(intl.formatMessage({
                            id: "error.commonServerError"
                        }))
                    }
                }
            }).catch(error => {
                dispatch(actions.errorEditPersonalDetails())
                setError(intl.formatMessage({
                    id: "error.commonServerError"
                }))
            })
        }
    }, [newName, newEmail, requestPhoneValue, requestCountryValue, isSaveBtnActive])

    // handle response change
    React.useEffect(() => {
        setNewName(name)
    }, [name, setNewName, shouldShowModal])

    React.useEffect(() => {
        setNewEmail(email)
    }, [email, setNewEmail, shouldShowModal])

    React.useEffect(() => {
        setNewPhone(phoneNumber)
        setRequestPhoneValue(phoneNumber)
    }, [phoneNumber, setNewPhone, setRequestPhoneValue, shouldShowModal])

    React.useEffect(() => {
        setNewCountry(getCountryFromCode(country))
        setRequestCountryValue(country)
    }, [country, setNewCountry, setRequestCountryValue, shouldShowModal])

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setNewPhoneCode(phoneCode)
  }, [phoneCode, setNewPhoneCode, shouldShowModal])

    return (
        <div onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}>
            <Modal 
                show={shouldShowModal} 
                onHide={_handleOnModalHide}
                className="editModal"
                backdropClassName="edit-details-modal-backdrop-custom"
                centered>
                <FormContainer>
                    <BlockUi tag="div" blocking={isRequestLoading}>
                        <Modal.Header className="editModalHeader" closeButton>
                            <Modal.Title>
                                <FormattedMessage id="modal.editPersonalDetails.title"/>
                            </Modal.Title>
                        </Modal.Header>
                        <Modal.Body>
                            <Form>
                                <Form.Group controlId="formBasicPhoneNumber">
                                    <ModalPhoneInput 
                                        initialValue={newPhone}
                                        changeCallback={_phoneChangeCallback}
                    countryChangeCallback={_phoneCountryCodeChangeCallback}
                    defaultCountryCode={newPhoneCode}/>
                                </Form.Group>

                                <SaveDetailsBtn 
                                    disabled={!isSaveBtnActive}
                                    onClick={_handleSaveBtnClick}>
                                    <FormattedMessage id="modal.editPersonalDetails.save"/>
                                </SaveDetailsBtn>
                            </Form>
                        </Modal.Body>
                    </BlockUi>
                </FormContainer>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    )
}
```

And the PhoneNumberInput file:

```
const PhoneNumberInput = ({ initialValue, customPlaceholder, changeCallback,countryChangeCallback, defaultCountryCode, ...props }) =>  {

    const [countryCode, setCountryCode] = React.useState(defaultCountryCode.toUpperCase())

    const _handleOnCountryCodeChange = React.useCallback((code) => {
        countryChangeCallback(code)
    },[countryChangeCallback])

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if(defaultCountryCode) {
            const countryCodeUpper = defaultCountryCode.toUpperCase()
            setCountryCode(countryCodeUpper)
        }
    },[defaultCountryCode])

    return (
        <PhoneInputWrapper>
            <StyledPhoneInput
                value={value}
                onChange={_handleOnChange} 
                defaultCountry={countryCode}
                onCountryChange={_handleOnCountryCodeChange}  />
        </PhoneInputWrapper>
    )
}
```

I've tried logging the values of `newPhoneNumber` and it's working as expected except that when I change the value and close the modal or try to save it, it logs undefined and I get a white screen.

[image: error]

Answer (score 2):

You're probably unmounting a component which does some ajax request and then based on respone it updates the state. Component has been unmounted before getting response back but the function goes on and tries to update state of component which is no longer mounted.

The appropirate way to handle this is storing requests in some array which will persist through rerenders (in useRef for example). Then on component unmounting, in the useEffect cleanup function make use of the Abort Controller API.

This article may help you: https://medium.com/@selvaganesh93/how-to-clean-up-subscriptions-in-react-components-using-abortcontroller-72335f19b6f7